# Аналог product из python itertools в С#

Tags: python, c#, комбинаторика

Мой код перебирает все возможные комбинации символов ABC в словах длиной в 5 символов и выводит их количество. Как записать этот код на C#?

```
from itertools import product
combinations = product("ABC", repeat=5)
count = 0
for i in combinations:
    count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Прямое произведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (Cartesian Product) можно вычислить так

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T[]> MyProduct<T>(T[][] items)
{
    int length = items.Length;
    int[] indexes = new int[length];

    while (true)
    {
        T[] arr = new T[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = items[i][indexes[i]];
        }
        yield return arr;

        int row = length - 1;
        indexes[row]++;
        while (indexes[row] == items[row].Length)
        {
            if (row == 0)
                yield break;
            indexes[row] = 0;
            row--;
            indexes[row]++;
        }
    }
}
```

А ваш код записать так

```cs
char[][] chars = Enumerable.Repeat("ABC".ToCharArray(), 5).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(MyProduct(chars).Count());
```

Вывод в консоль

```
243
```

Подробный разбор решения я публиковал ранее [здесь](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/254877/226545).